# How do I switch a branch in Git?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have executed the line below to switch to a new branch created by my teammate:

```
git checkout with-backend
```

I'm receiving the error below:

> error: pathspec 'with-backend' did not match any file(s) known to git

I tried executing this command:

```
git branch -a
```

The *with-backend* branch created by my teammate is not listed. Below is the result listed:

```
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
```

Comment: Try issuing `git fetch` before executing these commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you always pull latest changes from repo, before starting to work

git fetch <-- fetches all the latest changes from remote repo

OR

git pull <-- It is one step ahead of git fetch, it fetches remote changes and also merge local branch with remote branch

Answer (score 6):

First, switching branch is done with [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) (since Git 2.23, Q3 2019), not [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) (which tries to manage both files and branches, making it [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))

Second, `git switch with-backend` will work after `git fetch` because if its "guessing" mode:

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```